# How to get value from same class name div in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get value of div class ln24 which is Rs. 2000

```
<div class="ln24">
    <a class="cblack" href="http://www.sample.com/kerala/">Vasant Kunj</a>
    <span class="search-result-address" >Address</span>
</div>

<div class="ln24">
    <span class="upc grey-text sml">Cost for 2: </span>
    Rs. 2000
</div>
```

I have tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.ln24').each(function() {
        var cost = $(this).text();
    });      
});
```

Comment: only second `<div class="ln24">` div value you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('.ln24').clone().children().remove().end().text().trim();
 //           ^        ^         ^       ^
//            1        2         3       4
```

> 1. Creating a clone
> 2. Select all child elements into clone
> 3. Remove all child elements into the clone
> 4. Get the matched/filtered clone element

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9P2A/1/)

I think, the above trick helps you. But there is a problem if your other divs have some inner text. the text will include into your output. Please **[See the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/d9P2A/2/)**

If you always want to get the last div text, than you can use [.last()](http://api.jquery.com/last/).

```
$('.ln24').last().clone().children().remove().end().text().trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.contents()` at this context to filter out the required text,

```
var cost= $('.ln24:not(:has(a))').contents().last().text();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ujMYX/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("ln24")[0].lastChild.textContent;
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9f88h/)**

Comment: @upvoter - Milind Anantwar answer is right but is in javascript The OP tag only in jquery.Rajaprabhu answered in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
Get html element with `class="ln24"` and clone it. Now get children of cloned object and remove them, so now you will have only label part in the cloned object. Read lable i.e. cost using `.text()` method

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var cost = $('.ln24').last().clone().children().remove().end().text();
   alert(cost);
 });
```

Comment: Could you explain *why* your code provides a solution to the question?

Comment: It is reading cost for second .ln24 div .. this is what OP want.

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your code in your answer. At 5k rep you should know not to post code-only answers.

Comment: @Qix, added explaination in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ln24").on("click" , function(){

       $(".ln24").toggle();
        return false;
});
```

This's once example of mine :)

Comment: this is not an answer for these question